# Find $a,b,c$ if $f(4)=1, f(-2)=14, f(5)=-2$ and $f(x)=ax^2 + bx + c$

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

Would anyone please explain to me the steps needed in order to find $a,b,c$? I understand I must use elimination, but the answers I keep on getting are very unrealistic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are on the good track! Let write down the linear system in a,b,and c and solve that by elimination. You can show your work here and we can check that. What is the unrealistic result you have obtained?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Just consider the conditions

- $f(4)=1 \implies 16a+4b+c=1$
- $f(-2)=14 \implies \ldots$
- $f(5)=-2 \implies \ldots$

and solve the linear system you obtain to find $a$,$b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Solve the system
$$f(4)=16a+4b+c=1$$
$$f(-2)=4a-2b+c=14$$
$$f(5)=25a+5b+c=-2$$
for $$a,b,c$$